# Graphviz labels appearing if you hover over them?

Tags: python-3.x, graphviz

I am currently using graphviz through Python 3.x to visualize a digraph with info on the nodes and edges as graphviz-labels. This gets crowded, quite fast.
Therefore, I was wondering whether there is a possibility to have the label info appear when you hover your cursor over the corresponding node or edge?

With kind regards,
Tobi

Edit: I have given up on that issue for now. I looked into the python-graphviz-package, but to me it seemed as if the tooltip-parameter does not get passed on properly.

Answer (score 2):

You did not mention your desired output format.  If you are producing **SVG** output, read the attribute documentation about **tooltip**.

```
somenode [label="small" tooltip="thanks for asking, over the last few years..."]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I am not too sure about the output format. I get a .gv-file and also a pdf-file is automatically created. I have taken a look into the .gv-file and the entry appears `somenode [label="foo" tooltip="bar"]` , but it seems like it is not displayed in the pdf. However, I am not absolutely sure about that. Do you have any suggestions which format to use and what tool to view it with?

Comment: While it may be technically possible to do what you want with pdf, Graphviz does not support tooltip capability for pdf - only SVG.  So I suggest SVG.  Every (?) current web browser (firefox, chrome, safafi, edge,...) will display SVG files without problem.